# HTML page is not displaying all records but overwriting previous results

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

I have two child records under Sensor, but its only displaying the last one, since it overwrites the previous record. How can I display the two results under each other or side by side?

This section in code is the one pulling records from Firebase realtime database.

```
            get(child(dbref, "Sensor"))
            .then((snapshot)=>{
                snapshot.forEach((child)=>{
                    id_PumpID.innerHTML = "Pump ID: " + child.val().PumpID
                    id_StartTime.innerHTML = "StartTime: " + child.val().StartTime;
                    id_Cycle.innerHTML = "Cycle: " + child.val().Cycle;
                    id_Duration.innerHTML = "Duration: " +  child.val().Duration;
                    id_GalsPumped.innerHTML ="GalsPumped: " + child.val().GalsPumped;
                 })
                });
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="pump">
        <br><br>
        <h3 id="id_Cycle" type="number"></h3>
        <h3 id="id_Duration" type="number"></h3>
        <h3 id="id_GalsPumped" type="number"></h3>
        <h3 id="id_PumpID" type="number"></h3>
        <h3 id="id_StartTime" type="text"></h3>
        <br><br>
    </div>


    <script type="module">

          // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
          import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.4/firebase-app.js";

          //config firebase
          const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-qE4zUGw",
            authDomain: "pump-a559c.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://pump-a559c-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "pump-a559c",
            storageBucket: "pump-a559c.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "838180391277",
            appId: "1:838180391277:web:df22c7d634310ae135b264",
            measurementId: "G-K66Z05LFCD"
          };

          // Initialize Firebase
          const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

          import {getDatabase, set, get, update, remove, ref, child}
          from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.4/firebase-database.js";

          const db = getDatabase();
          const dbref = ref(db);

            get(child(dbref, "Sensor"))
            .then((snapshot)=>{
                snapshot.forEach((child)=>{
                    id_PumpID.innerHTML = "Pump ID: " + child.val().PumpID
                    id_StartTime.innerHTML = "StartTime: " + child.val().StartTime;
                    id_Cycle.innerHTML = "Cycle: " + child.val().Cycle;
                    id_Duration.innerHTML = "Duration: " +  child.val().Duration;
                    id_GalsPumped.innerHTML ="GalsPumped: " + child.val().GalsPumped;
                 })
                });
        window.onload();

      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with switch - case statements. Please see the full code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Drainage Pump Monitor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <style type="text/css">
    .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
    .tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
      overflow:hidden;padding:13px 14px;word-break:normal;}
    .tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
      font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:13px 14px;word-break:normal;}
    .tg .tg-l183{background-color:#96fffb;border-color:inherit;font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace !important;font-size:16px;
      font-weight:bold;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
    .tg .tg-0pky{border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
    </style>

    <header>
        <h1>DRAINAGE PLAN</h1>
        <h2>7310 S Cypresshead dr, Parkland FL 33067</h2>
    </header>

    <main>
        <h2>Pump Monitor</h2>
        <table id="pump_table" style="margin-top:130px; margin-left:10px;" class="tg" align="right">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="tg-l183">PUMP</th>
            <th class="tg-l183">START-TIME</th>
            <th class="tg-l183">DURATION(mins)</th>
            <th class="tg-l183">PUMPED(gals)</th>
            <th class="tg-l183">CYCLE</th>
            <th class="tg-l183">STATUS</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        </table>
    </main>
    <footer>
       <p>Copyright &copy; <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script>, Innovative-Appliances. LLC </p>
    </footer>

    <script type="module">

        // Import firebase app
        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.4/firebase-app.js";

        // Configure Firebase
        const firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
          databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
          projectId: "pump-a559c",
          storageBucket: "pump-a559c.appspot.com",
          messagingSenderId: "838180391277",
          appId: "1:838180391277:web:df22c7d634310ae135b264",
          measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        };

        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        // Import the Firebase database
        import {getDatabase, set, get, update, remove, ref, child}
        from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.4/firebase-database.js";

        const db = getDatabase();
        const dbref = ref(db);
        const heartBeat = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);

        get(child(dbref, "Sensor"))
        .then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((child) => {
            var bg_color = '#00FF00';
            console.log(child.val().Heartbeat);
            console.log("html heartbeat" + heartBeat);
            // Check the heartbeat and report power failure if not found

            if(child.val().Heartbeat < (heartBeat - 15))
            {
                console.log("no heart beat detected");
                let table = document.querySelector('table');
                let template = `
                    <tr>
                       <td bgcolor='red'>${"pump" + child.val().PumpID}</td>
                       <td bgcolor='red'>CONTROLLER FAILURE</td>
                    </tr>`;
                table.innerHTML += template;

            } else {

                 switch (child.val().Status) {

                   case "OFF":

                      // Set the color of row to red if no water flow is detected.
                      bg_color = 'yellow';

                      let table = document.querySelector('table');
                      let template = `
                          <tr>
                             <td bgcolor="${bg_color}">${"pump"+child.val().PumpID}</td>
                             <td bgcolor="${bg_color}">${child.val().StartTime}</td>
                             <td bgcolor="${bg_color}">${child.val().Duration}</td>
                             <td bgcolor="${bg_color}">${child.val().GalsPumped}</td>
                             <td bgcolor="${bg_color}">${child.val().Cycle}</td>
                             <td bgcolor="${bg_color}">${child.val().Status}</td>
                          </tr>`;
                          table.innerHTML += template;
                          break;

                   case "ON":
                           // Set the color of row to green
                           // if water flow is detected.
                           bg_color = '#00FF00';

                           let table2 = document.querySelector('table');
                           let template2 = `
                               <tr>
                                  <td bgcolor="${bg_color}">${"pump"+child.val().PumpID}</td>
                                  <td bgcolor="${bg_color}">${child.val().StartTime}</td>
                                  <td bgcolor="${bg_color}">${child.val().Duration}</td>
                                  <td bgcolor="${bg_color}">${child.val().GalsPumped}</td>
                                  <td bgcolor="${bg_color}">${child.val().Cycle}</td>
                                  <td bgcolor="${bg_color}">${child.val().Status}</td>
                               </tr>`;
                               table2.innerHTML += template2;
                         break;

                   case "FAIL":
                       // Set the color of row to red
                       // if pump failure is detected.
                       bg_color = 'red';

                       let table3 = document.querySelector('table');
                       let template3 = `
                         <tr>
                            <td bgcolor='red'>${"pump" + child.val().PumpID}</td>
                            <td bgcolor='red'>PUMP FAILURE</td>
                         </tr>`;
                           table3.innerHTML += template3;
                       break;

                  } // End of switch
            }  // End of else
          })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```